# systemd job failing No such file or Directory

Tags: linux, systemd

have been trying to follow this script to start airflow

https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-automatically-execute-shell-script-at-startup-boot-on-systemd-linux

So i have the following sh file in /usr/local/bin/airflow-start-all.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "starting up postgres service"
export AIRFLOW_HOME=~/airflow
sudo service postgresql start
echo "sleeping"
sleep 15
echo "initiating database"
airflow initdb
echo "sleeping"
sleep 15
gnome-terminal -e /home/ubuntu/Source/Bash/airflow-start-webserver.sh
sleep 15
echo "starting rabbitmq service"
sudo service rabbitmq-server start
sleep 15
gnome-terminal -e /home/ubuntu/Source/Bash/airflow-start-scheduler.sh
sleep 15
gnome-terminal -e /home/ubuntu/Source/Bash/airflow-start-worker.sh
```

and the following file in /etc/systemd/system/airflow-start-service.service

```
[Unit]
Description=My last command
After=default.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/airflow-start-all.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

I have run

```
sudo chmod 744 /usr/local/bin/airflow-start-all.sh
```

and

```
sudo chmod 664 /etc/systemd/system/airflow-service-start.service
```

and also

```
systemctl daemon-reload
systemctl enable disk-space-check.service
```

And it doesnt seem to start the services on startup - all I get is:

```
● airflow-service-start.service - My last command
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/airflow-service-start.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2018-05-02 00:23:00 UTC; 1h 21min ago
  Process: 1587 ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/airflow-start-all.sh (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 1587 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

May 02 00:22:30 sudo[1658]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
May 02 00:22:45 airflow-start-all.sh[1587]: Failed to connect to Mir: Failed to connect to server socket: No such file or directory
May 02 00:22:45 airflow-start-all.sh[1587]: Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused
May 02 00:22:45  airflow-start-all.sh[1587]: Failed to parse arguments: Cannot open display:
May 02 00:23:00 airflow-start-all.sh[1587]: Failed to connect to Mir: Failed to connect to server socket: No such file or directory
May 02 00:23:00 airflow-start-all.sh[1587]: Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused
May 02 00:23:00 airflow-start-all.sh[1587]: Failed to parse arguments: Cannot open display:
May 02 00:23:00  systemd[1]: airflow-service-start.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
May 02 00:23:00  systemd[1]: airflow-service-start.service: Unit entered failed state.
May 02 00:23:00  systemd[1]: airflow-service-start.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

Any idea where I have gone wrong?

Thanks,
Tim

Comment: `sudo chmod 744 /usr/local/bin/airflow-start-all.sh` are you sure the systemd user runs as `root` and not `nobody` (or equivalent for your distro?) The problem seems to be `Failed to connect to Mir: Failed to connect to server socket: No such file or directory` What is `Mir?`. Your question is a close call, but it is more "How do I setup Airflow?" than actually being programming related. You should migrate the question to [**Super User**](http://superuser.com/).